# using mono to host a asp.net owin webpage on the pi results in bad host

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, raspberry-pi, owin

While i was trying to port a owin asp.net website to the pi, (raspberry pi model b) I ended up with a website displaying the error page :

> Bad Request (Invalid host)

On the pi i am running raspbian wheezy. I installed mono (version 3.2.8).
For a simple console aplication mono works.

 for the Owin website i made a console project in visual studio 2015.

To this console aplication i added the nuget packages :

`Microsoft.Owin`

`Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics`

`Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListner`

`Microsoft.Owin.Hosting`

After that i added a Owin startup class. Within this class i added a few lines of code to display the current os":

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseWelcomePage(new Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics.WelcomePageOptions()
    {
        Path = new PathString("/welcome")
    });

    app.Run(context =>
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        string output = string.Format(
            "I'm running on {0} nFrom assembly {1}",
            Environment.OSVersion,
            System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().FullName
            );

        return context.Response.WriteAsync(output);

    });
}
```

Now i only needed to specify the base url of the project within the program class, id did this in the main function

```
    string baseUrl = "http://localhost:5000";
    using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(baseUrl))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit.");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

With this code my project gives on startup a console view with the text

> Press Enter to quit.

When i browse to

> http://localhost:5000

The webpage gives the folowing output:

> I'm running on Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0 nFrom assembly
>   ConsoleApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null

however when I copy all my dll's and exe to my pi and execute the command

> Mono ConsoleApplication1.exe

the pi gives the line Press Enter to quit. but when i browse to the ip of the pi  with the port number 500, in my case

> http://192.168.7.137:5000/

The webpage displayes Bad Request (Invalid host)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
http://localhost:5000
```

to

```
http://*:5000
```

Comment: although this did not work it gave me a nudge in the correct direction. TY!.  change it not into http://*:5000 but into the correct ip in my case http://192.168.7.137:5000. but this makes me wonder is there a way to make this more generic

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the direction rtf_leg pointed me the localhost is not available when accecsing the website from the pi.

i only had to change the base url to the exact url of the pi. in my case http://192.168.7.137:5000.

this way the pi knew what to do when the url was accesed and the rusult shown was :

> I'm running on Unix 3.18.7.0 nFrom assembly ConsoleApplication1,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

:D

Comment: In my answer asterisk in baseUrl means "any IP adddres". I our case this means that the process is listening on all of the IP addresses the machine has. It is not good idea to use fixed IP adress beacuse it can be changed by some reason and you would rewrite baseUrl value again and again.

Comment: the ip iadress in your awnser http://*:5000 gives an exception when trying to run on the pi i now use the hostname to determain the ip and use that.

Comment: @Ivan Sander de Jong, After much experimentation, I disagree with  you, Have you tried Alias Match with the regular expression \.(aspx|jpg|gif|png)$  ? Thanks.